# Is the use of @ instead of 'a' or 'o' in order to refer to both masculine and feminine accepted?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, ortografía, género, neutralidad-de-género, deletreo

I have seen several times the use of @ instead of 'a' or 'o' for referring to masculine and feminine words at the same time. For example:

> Hola a tod@s.

Is this an accepted use?

Comment: It's very informal and mostly used on the internet, you won't find it in newspapers,TV, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to Wikipedia ([English article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign#Gender-neutrality_in_Spanish_and_Portuguese), [Spanish article](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arroba_(s%C3%ADmbolo)#Uso_de_la_arroba_para_indicar_ambos_g.C3.A9neros)), the use of the at sign (arroba) as a combination of *o* and *a* for gender-neutrality reasons has been growing in recent years. Proponents see it as a useful means of achieving [gender-neutral spelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender-neutrality_in_Spanish_and_Portuguese). Opponents argue that the *-o* ending already encompasses both sexes, and the use of the at sign is unnecessary and awkward.

The Real Academia Española (RAE) officially disapproves of this practice in [Section 2.2 of the *Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas*'s chapter on Gender](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=g%E9nero#22), saying:

> Para evitar las engorrosas repeticiones a que da lugar la reciente e innecesaria costumbre de hacer siempre explícita la alusión a los dos sexos (los niños y las niñas, los ciudadanos y ciudadanas, etc.; → 2.1), ha comenzado a usarse en carteles y circulares el símbolo de la arroba (@) como recurso gráfico para integrar en una sola palabra las formas masculina y femenina del sustantivo, ya que este signo parece incluir en su trazo las vocales a y o: l@s niñ@s. Debe tenerse en cuenta que la arroba no es un signo lingüístico y, por ello, su uso en estos casos es inadmisible desde el punto de vista normativo; a esto se añade la imposibilidad de aplicar esta fórmula integradora en muchos casos sin dar lugar a graves inconsistencias, como ocurre en Día del niñ@, donde la contracción del solo es válida para el masculino niño.

As a side note, I've noticed the at sign used in this way as you arrive at the airport in Managua, Nicaragua:

[image: BIENVENID@S]

Comment: Como he comentado, es un tema bastante espinoso y en mi opinión no lleva a ningún sitio, al igual que el añadir el genero femenino a ciertas profesiones.

Answer (score 6):

La [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=g%E9nero2#22) no ha incluido el uso de la "@" para abreviar las frases que poseen elementos/personas/profesiones... al mismo tiempo.

El uso de este "truco" o abreviatura es limitado, y no lo verás en escritos serios (periódicos,libros...) y ahora mismo está limitado a, y esto puede acarrear un poco de debate "político", un intento de quitar  "un toque machista" que tiene el castellano (uso del masculino para referirse a grupos en los que también hay mujeres por ejemplo).

En mi opinión el uso de la "@" no se va a extender u oficializar al menos a corto plazo.

Parecido a este caso, y motivado por una corriente feminista, se ha intentado "feminizar" ciertas palabras masculinas, sobretodo de profesiones, que no poseen variante femenina.
Ejemplos:

> El médico, la médica
>   El piloto, la pilota
>   El presidente, la presidenta
>   El miembro, la miembra

Personalmente me parece un error puesto que el lenguaje es el que es y también existen ejemplos contrarios (palabras femeninas que se refieren a ambos sexos), por ejemplo el futbolista (no se dice el futbolisto, que por cierto sería gracioso :D ) y no se ha motivado el cambio.

**Sorry, the question is very problematic and I prefer writing in Spanish to avoid confusion in the answer.**

Comment: There's nothing wrong answering in spanish (see FAQ) so don't worry :)

Comment: "-ista" nunca ha sido femenino. Es neutro (periodista, taxista, machista, feminista, realista...). El único ejemplo contrario que se me ocurre es "modisto", aunque "modista" también vale para hombres. [DPD](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=modista)

Comment: Technicamente, estas profesiones no son «masculinas» cuando se refiere al individuo.  Se las consideran «invariables». Igualmente, _ista_ no es neutro, sino invariable.  El español no tiene sustantivos neutros para eso se tendría que ir al rumano o al asturiano.  Hay divisas como «policía», «brigada» que normalmente son palabras femeninas (refiriéndose al cuerpo, o a un grupo de escuadrones) pero como individuos se consideran palabras invariables (el policía, el brigada)