# ¿Cómo se llama al empleado de un banco? Banquero parece designar solamente al dueño

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Con frecuencia me surge la duda de cómo se llamará un empleado *raso* de una empresa bancaria. A saber, la persona que te atiende en la ventanilla, o incluso el director de una sucursal.

[*Banquero*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4yQDnIb) designa:

> Dueño o alto directivo de una entidad bancaria.

Por lo que las personas a las que me refiero no estarían representadas en esta definición.

Entonces, ¿hay algún nombre para designar a un empleado de banca?

Comment: simplemente **empleado de banca**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

¡Se le llama ***bancario***!

Del DLE:

> [**bancario, ria**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4wd3lRI)
>
> 1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la banca o a los [bancos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4wkKYpU#LwOapkB) (‖ empresas dedicadas a operaciones financieras). Entidades bancarias.
> 2. m. y f. Empleado de [banco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4wkKYpU#LwOapkB) (‖ empresa dedicada a operaciones financieras).

Y efectivamente, a esta definición llegué a través de una noticia en la que habla de [*Enric Montefusco, el exbancario punk que nació en la Meridiana*](https://www.elperiodico.com/es/noticias/onbarcelona/escuchar/enric-montefusco-meridiana-5675058), un señor que era empleado de banca.

Fundéu da fe de ello en [*Banquero o bancario*](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/banquero-o-bancario-15905/).

Comment: empleado bancario 
esto es correcto !, aunque honestamente, no creo que se deba utilizar el termino de esa manera, si no que deberia utilizarse de acuerdo a su profesion. es como decir que quien trabaja en un restaurante es un restaurantario, o un empleado de una fabrica es un fabricario.

Comment: De acuerdo pero me voy más con la respuesta de @alvalongo. _Bancario_ es relativo al banco. SI es un empleado entonces es _empleado bancario_ si es un edificio, pues, _edificio bancario_. Creo que es indispensable especificar el objeto y dejar _bancario_ como adjetivo.

Comment: @DGaleano el [Mapa de Diccionarios](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub) nos indica que la incorporación de _bancario_ como sustantivo es muy reciente. Siempre se había usado como adjetivo. Desconozco la manera de buscar palabras por su categoría gramatical y ver la tendencia de uso en, por ejemplo, Google, pero que el DLE lo incluya así es sintomático de que de alguna forma lo de _empleado bancario_ ha ido evolucionando hasta dejarlo en _bancario_, que un sector importante de gente debe reconocer (yo no lo conocía, pero entiendo que la RAE trabaja con criterios potentes de uso).

Comment: @fedorqui entiendo que la fuente es la RAE pero como decimos aquí "son muy olímpicos" en aceptar usos sin decir donde se usa. La muestra de usuarios de este stack no ha mostrado que en ninguno de los países representados sea el caso. De todas formas si la RAE lo dice, es la ley :-) Sustantivar adjetivos y adjetivar sustantivos es lo que hacemos todo el tiempo :-D

Answer (score 4):

En Colombia se acostumbra decir "empleado bancario" para referirse a la persona que trabaja para un banco, sin determinar cuál es la labor que realiza para el banco, por ejemplo:

> los empleados bancarios hicieron huelga para solicitar aumento de
>   salario

La palabra "banquero" se usa particularmente para referirse a la persona o personas que sean el o los accionistas mayoritarios de un banco. En el siguiente ejemplo se hace referencia a una persona real en Colombia que es accionista mayoritario de 5 bancos:

> El Sr. Luis Carlos Sarmiento Angulo es uno de los principales banqueros de
>   Colombia

Answer (score 2):

Si el empleado hace servicio directo al cliente creo que sería apto decir

**cajero/cajera**

pero si el contexto no indica claramente *banco* entonces habría que ampliar esto a *cajer@ del banco*. Creo que "cajer@" es equivalente al "teller" de inglés, solo que ahí, "teller" solo se usa para bancos, así que ahí no hace falta agregar nada; sin embargo, a veces se agrega "bank" de todas maneras: "bank teller."

Cuando se llama por teléfono para hablar con un representante que da servicio al cliente, entonces no se puede usar ni *cajer@* ni *teller*.  En este caso creo que se utilizaría un término más general -- *representante*, etc.

Para mí, "bancario" me sugiere alguien que está un poco alto en la jerarquía del banco.  Si llamara para ajustar mis (hipotéticas) inversiones, creo que hablaría con un bancario.  Si llamara para pedir un préstamo, creo que hablaría con un *oficial de préstamos* o quizás también un bancario.  Pero si llamara para transferir un dinero a la cuenta de mi hijo, creo que sería un término más general -- hablaría con, por ejemplo, un *representante del banco.*

Comment: _Para mí, "bancario" me sugiere alguien que está un poco alto en la jerarquía del banco_. No, mira la definición del DLE: es un término genérico para persona que trabaja en un banco. Y [_cajero_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6eFNou5) es algo muy concreto y genérico a la vez: se usa para muchos entornos (no solo la banca) y se refiere solamente al que está en la caja, cuando yo pregunto en general.

Comment: En cuanto al uso de _cajer@_ en lugar de _cajero/a_, actualmente se ve muy raro y cada vez tiene un registro más informal. Véase [Is the use of @ instead of 'a' or 'o' in order to refer to both masculine and femenine accepted?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/342/1674).

Comment: @fedorqui - Me quedó clara la teoría.  En cuanto al uso en la práctica, será interesante ver los comentarios y votos.  Hace 11 o 12 años que no voy a México, por eso siento tanta incertidumbre con muchas cosas del español. Si comparo con "banker" en inglés, no se utilizaría este término en EEUU para la gran mayoría del personal del banco. ¿Podrías hacer un poco de investigación de campo, y preguntar la próxima vez que tengas que ir o llamar al banco? // Con respecto al signo @ -- este tema es muy interesante.  ¿Te gustaría actualizar esa página?  Yo me estaba preguntando eso precisamente.

Comment: Efectivamente, lo de _bancario_ apenas se usa. Por eso publiqué la pregunta, pues fui el primer sorprendido al descubrir el término como nombre. Lo que se estila es decir _trabaja en un banco_, para diferenciar el empleo de un amigo (si es que ese amigo no se apellida Botín :D). _Cajero_ se vería incluso despectivo, pues la mayoría de gente que trabaja en un banco acaba haciendo más cosas que atender la caja.

Comment: @fedorqui - Interesante. Donde vivo hay muchísimos cajeros que no hacen más que atender la caja, y por cierto, no ganan muy bien.

Comment: Entiendo. En España, y especialmente desde los tiempos de la crisis y los rescates bancarios, el número de establecimientos bancarios se ha reducido dramáticamente. Y lo mismo con la cantidad de empleados, que en general han pasado a tener una función cercana a la del comercial.

Comment: @fedorqui - Ah, entiendo ahora. Lo mismo he visto en visitas a Alemania.

Comment: En Argentina, *bancario* es equivalente a *empleado bancario*, sea quien sea, aunque a un gerente no se lo llama habitualmente así. Hay una connotación de "empleado sindicalizado". Un *cajero* es un bancario que atiende la caja. Hoy en día no obstante un *cajero* es más bien un ATM y se suele tener que aclarar *cajero humano*.

Comment: @pablodf76 - Interesante!  Pero en el supermercado, tienen cajeros?

Comment: Primero decir que cuando uno habla de un empleado de banco no se refiere usualmente a los de TI o al gerente o los que hacen el café sino a los que atienden directamente al público. En estos hay unas pocas clases y en Colombia les decimos según su función. **Cajero** es el que te atiende en la *mayoría* de las transacciones y **asesor** son los que te ayudan a resolver problemas, te asesoran en la solicitud de créditos y/o en la apertura o cancelación de servicios del banco. Para Colombia aplica esta respuesta +1

Comment: @aparente001 Sí, claro. De los humanos. :)

Comment: @DGaleano veo que mi pregunta ha ido cogiendo vuelo y que se observa ya la diferencia entre la estructura de las sucursales bancarias según el país. Como decía más arriba, en España actualmente es raro ver a alguien dedicado únicamente a ser _cajero_: se hace lo posible para que la gente no vaya al banco con dinero, sino más bien a realizar gestiones de banca.